# Remove class from img inside "a" tag with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that gets the contents of a table row and displays each cells content in a different part of the page. This works great, but I need to remove a class from an image which is inside an a tag. The variable looks like this:

```
var bilde=$('span[id^="foto"]', this).find('a').html();
```

And is outputed to the other part of the page like this:

```
$('.bilde').html(bilde);
```

When I use firebug, i see that the contents of .bilde is outputted like this:

```
<div class="bilde">
<img id="foto2" class="previewImage" src="images/upload/thumb/516467.jpg">
</div>
```

How can I remove the class "previewImage" from that image, but ONLY from the image that is displayed inside ".bilde". I've played around the the .removeClass, but with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
$("div.bilde").find("img").removeClass("previewImage");
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/D5APn/

Comment: Worked just as i intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".bilde").children(".previewImage").removeClass("previewImage");
```

Place after you set the html of div.bilde.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Perfect!